# What is the cause of this AngularJS error?

Tags: angularjs

I am very new to AngularJS. After upgrading to the 1.3.6 version, I get the following error:

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.6/ng/areq?p0=myController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
```

What is undefined here?

BTW, I got another error something like "$http is not defined" in the 1.2.x version.

Also, after the upgrading, the following code is no longer working.

```
<div id="sizeNStyle-panel" ng-show="toggle">
<table class="table-striped" ng-show="toggle">
   ...
</table>
<div id="add-sizeNstyle-panel" ng-hide="toggle">
   ...
   <button ng-click="toggle = !toggle" >Show Data</button>
</div>
```

The controller is defined as what it shall be. I have CDATA to prevent Thymeleaf parsing the Javascript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
/*<![CDATA[*/ 
   ...
/*]]>*/
```

Not sure whether it is a problem or not.

Answer (score 0):

I searched this up online and I found out that it is probably because that the value the assertion expects is not defined and truthy. Your assertion is probably the source of the error. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for your input. But, I don't know what assertion you are talking about. I try to identify which field's problem. As I know from the URL, something is wrong inside of the controller. What is p0 and p1?

Answer (score 0):

I find that the 1.3 version is no longer accepting a global controller definition. I need something like

```
angular.module('myapp', []).controller('MyController', function myController($scope) {
  ....
}
```